# Combining queries into an ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi I'm working on a project and I need to take result of two database queries and combine them into one ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation, at the moment I have:

```
results.where(pos_or_neg: "neg").order("value DESC") + (results.where(pos_or_neg: "pos").order("value ASC"))
```

However this returns an array which doesn't work as I need to do more processing afterwards. I've tried:

```
results.where(pos_or_neg: "neg").order("value DESC").merge(results.where(pos_or_neg: "pos").order("value ASC"))
```

but this only seems to return the half of the results.

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `value`? Is it integer or float or string?

Comment: It's a date type.

Answer (score 0):

results.order("pos_or_neg ASC,case when pos_or_neg="neg" then value else -1*value end DESC")

Answer (score 0):

I believe using merge is the equivalent of an AND query in SQL. What you are looking for is an OR query.
Since Rails 5 this is one of the Active Record query methods that you can use!
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or

Try to replace your .merge with .or and see if that works better

Comment: Unfortunately the project isn't using rails 5